# How to use functions properly Robotframework IMAP library

Tags: python, email, robotframework, imaplib, robotframework-browser

this is my first post (not native English) :)

I would like to use "Get Multipart Field Names". This function has a return value, but I can not give an argument which email (index) should be used. The documentation has few information without a proper example.
I tried many things. But I think this is my closest attempt:
 `@{fields}   Get Multipart Field Names`

I always get the error:
`Suspended due to logged failure: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'`

This is the function

```py
    def get_multipart_field_names(self):
        """Returns all available header field names of selected multipart email message.

        Examples:
        | Get Multipart Field Names |
        """
        return list(self._mp_msg.keys())
```

When I hover over "keys()" it says: "(function) keys: Any"

I just want to have the encoded email body, so I can decrypt some words of it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably keyword `walk Multipart Email` was not called prior to `Get Multipart Field Names`.

The probable order of keywords for your case could be :

1. `Open Mailbox    ...`
2. `${mail_index} =  wait for email ...`  - searching for email by status/subject etc
3. `walk Multipart Email  ${mail_index}` - creating some internal objects being necessary for other multipart keywords!
4. `${field_names} =  Get Multipart Field Names` - should work now.

Comment: Yeah, that worked, thank you very much!